# How remove from group in table

Tags: mysql

Exists table `temporary_meta_product` with structure

```
CREATE TABLE `temporary_meta_product` (
  `meta_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `product_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY `META_PRODUCT_UNIQUE` (`meta_product_id`,`product_code`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

and data

```
+ -------------------- + ----------------- +
| meta_product_id      | product_code      |
+ -------------------- + ----------------- +
| 54306361             | 3533719           |
| 54306361             | 3533720           |
| 54306361             | 3533721           |
| 54306361             | 3533722           |
| 54306361             | 3533723           |
| 54306361             | 3533724           |
| 54306361             | 3533725           |
| 54306361             | 3533726           |
| 54306361             | 3533727           |
| 54306361             | 3533728           |
+ -------------------- + ----------------- +
| 54306577             | 3533870           |
| 54306577             | 3533871           |
| 54306577             | 3533872           |
| 54306577             | 3533873           |
| 54306577             | 3533874           |
| 54306577             | 3533875           |
| 54306577             | 3533876           |
| 54306577             | 3533877           |
| 54306577             | 3533878           |
| 54306577             | 3533879           |
+ -------------------- + ----------------- +
```

Need reduce table or create new reduced
I new table need 5 rows or less for all `meta_product_id`, expect:

```
+ -------------------- + ----------------- +
| meta_product_id      | product_code      |
+ -------------------- + ----------------- +
| 54306361             | 3533719           |
| 54306361             | 3533720           |
| 54306361             | 3533721           |
| 54306361             | 3533722           |
| 54306361             | 3533723           |
| 54306577             | 3533870           |
| 54306577             | 3533871           |
| 54306577             | 3533872           |
| 54306577             | 3533873           |
| 54306577             | 3533874           |
| 54306784             | 3534021           |
| 54306784             | 3534022           |
+ -------------------- + ----------------- +
```

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/13187418/3470178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Naming (for brevity in my example) your table as t1, you can try following query:

```
SELECT meta_product_id, product_code 
 FROM (
     SELECT meta_product_id, product_code
     ,@r:= CASE WHEN @g=t1.meta_product_id THEN  @r+1 ELSE 1 END consecutive
     ,@g:=t1.meta_product_id
     FROM t1
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT @r:=1, @g:=-1) t1
     ORDER BY meta_product_id, product_code
     ) A
 WHERE consecutive <=5;
```

Comment: You can use `IF(@g=t1.meta_product_id, @r+1, 1) `

Comment: But you should use `IF(@g=t1.meta_product_id, @r+1, IF(@g:=t1.meta_product_id, 1, 1))` because assignment order for user variables isnt guaranted https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html   `However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.`

Comment: @Juan   Thanks for your observation.  But do you think it's also the case when there are two different variables? In the same manual you cited, some paragraphs later, they write "To avoid problems with this behavior, either do not assign a value to and read the value of the same variable within a single statement..." so it could seem they refer only at the "same variable".

Comment: I learn that from Gordon (if you know who he is). So I rather be safe than sorry.

Comment: @Juan I already saw I forgot it and added, thanks